# How to pass a struct member as an argument to a function? − C

Tags: c, struct, arguments, embedded, member

I'm trying to pass a member `TRISCbits.TRISC2` of a struct to a function.

microcontroller.h:

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned TRISC0                 :1;
        unsigned TRISC1                 :1;
        unsigned TRISC2                 :1;
    };
} TRISCbits_t;
extern volatile TRISCbits_t TRISCbits @ 0x014;
```

What I'd like to do:

user.c:

```
static void pwm5Init(volatile unsigned __bit* trisBit){
    *trisBit = 0;
}
```

I would like to pass the `TRISC2` bit as an argument: `pwm5Init(&TRISCbits.TRISC2)`.
And I want my function `pwm5Init` to modify the real `TRISC2` bit at address 0x14+3bits −not a local copy−

As you can't make a pointer point a bit, how would you do? What are the good practices?

Comment: Don't pass a bit, pass the whole structure.

Comment: Then, how can I pass the member I want my function to address?
If I pass the whole structure, the function has no way to know which member to modify

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why don't you just pass the address? And then do operations with that address.

Comment: Hi, thanks @TarekDakhran
As I said, can't pass an address to a bit, the minimum addressable type is `char`

Comment: You can pass it another parameter telling what to modify. Or don't let the function to modify it, but have it to return a value to be written back by the caller.

Comment: Isn't it too heavy to do that?

Comment: What architecture you work on?

Comment: I would not work with bitfields for that at all, but would pass the whole word or whatever and a mask to set/reset.

Comment: @TarekDakhran PIC16, Microchip

Comment: @EugeneSh. , thanks you can submit your suggestions as answers. One last thing, passing the structure first and the member second: How would you give the second parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not imagine a better example than [linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/mach-exynos/suspend.c#L357)

Here is the code fragment how to modify single bit

```
unsigned tmp;
// some code here
tmp = pmu_raw_readl(EXYNOS_L2_OPTION(0));
tmp &= ~EXYNOS_L2_USE_RETENTION;
pmu_raw_writel(tmp, EXYNOS_L2_OPTION(0));
```

The patter is read a word from memory, then modify the bit, then write a word.
I believe memory is addressed on a byte level. On some architectures even on a word level. So modifying a single bit with "native" instruction is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your example does not truly reflect what you wish to do but given:

```
static unsigned pwm5Init()
{
    return 0 ;
}
```

Then:

```
TRISCbits.TRISC2 = pwm5Init() ;
```

Will achieve the exact result you are proposing for your *impossible*:

```
static void pwm5Init(volatile unsigned __bit* trisBit){
    *trisBit = 0;
}
```

That is the "good practice".  If that does not achieve what you are asking, then you need a more realistic example perhaps?

In the case where you might need the current value, then:

```
static unsigned pwm5Init( unsigned bit )
{
    // flip the bit (for example)
    return ~bit & 1 ;
}
```

then:

```
TRISCbits.TRISC2 = pwm5Init( TRISCbits.TRISC2 ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks! That's also a clever way to achieve it. Quite intuitive

Comment: @TheJeje20 : I think it is pretty idiomatic. It is what some of the comments were suggesting.

Comment: Design wise I still see all here problematic, even the naming, because the bit you set with pwm5init is just one part of the whole PWM. How do you call then the timer setup (dutycycle/period), clock selection, in/out mode etc pp. because the pwm5init() let the "user" think, the whole PWM Chn5 is initialized, and you just need to set period and dutycycle and trigger it. That in C, the smalles addressable item is 1 Byte is just another topic. Rather have a PWM module, with an init function passing a channel number, and PWM module will init the complete PWM channel.

Comment: @kesselhaus : the naming is not mine.  That is in the original question, I retained it to indicate equivalence.  Either way the question is not specifically about PWM initialisation, I don't think it matters here, it is just an illustration of an idiom, not a question about hardware initialisation.  Your comment probably belongs against the question rather than this answer, but I think you are over thinking it.

Comment: @Clifford "It is what some of the comments were suggesting", yep I know :) But you gave illustration of what Eugene-sh said. Thanks for that

Comment: I confirm: my question wasn't about how to initialize a PWM channel. I only kept the relevant parts to illustrate my question ;)